# Static Dropdown Menu - Need to stop it moving position

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with the css position of my dropdown navigation menu now for some time and can't seem to get it to stay where it should.

An example of my menu can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/W8UFZ/

The CSS for the dropdown area is

```
.rscss-horizontal_nav ul li ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

When the page isn't scrolled down at all, the dropdown menu is fine. However when you scroll down a bit the menu doesn't move up to stay with the top level navigation item.

I can't seem to find what's causing this and have tried different position styles for the dropdown menu but still to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/W8UFZ/5/

Changes made:

```
 .rscss-horizontal_nav {
   /* remove overflow:hidden; here! */
 }

 .rscss-horizontal_nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    line-height: 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    position:relative;
}
 .rscss-horizontal_nav ul li ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:27px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

This should do the trick !

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.rscss-horizontal_nav ul li ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

may be it can help you..

Comment: This, when applied with the correct top value to make it appear at the correct position initially, still gives me the original issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

apply `position: fixed` as show in link

Check this fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/W8UFZ/2/

Added this in your CSS -

```
.rscss-horizontal_nav{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't descriptive enough in my original post, it's not the actual menu which I want to be static it's the dropdown menu when you roll over the navigation item. Thanks though